# How to undo a 'svn revert'?

Tags: linux, svn, version

I accidentially did an 'svn revert' and lost all my changes consequentially. 
Is there any possibility to get them back?
I'm on Linux and using the command line utility.

Answer (score 3):

Svn revert is inherently dangerous, since its entire purpose is to throw away data—namely, your uncommitted changes. Once you've reverted, Subversion provides no way to get back those uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `svn revert` command reverts local uncommitted (i.e. unpublished) modifications. There is no way to recover those modifications unless you use TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN puts reverted changes into Recycle Bin on Windows.